# Rails - Not uploading to heroku after upgrading ruby to 1.9.3 and rails to 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rbenv

I had this app using 1.9.2 and rails 3.2
and today I changed the ruby version into 1.9.3 (using rbenv)
and everything went wrong then

I had this on my gemfile

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

Everytime I run:

bundle install --without production

Nothing happens now and when I do

git push heroku master

I get the same error:

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.5) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
       /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
```

Its obviously trying to install sqlite, but even if I remove the sqlite gem from my Gemfile nothing happens, seems that the problem is in heroku but now I can't do nothing

Hope someone can help me because I was trying to do

heroku db:pull

and because of that I wanted to add the taps gem, then I followed this tutorial

http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html

And I changed the version of ruby in heroku, now I think that the problem is rbenv but I'm not sure

Thanks in advance

Javier Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in order to get all the db I only had to do:

```
gem install taps
```

and not to put it into the Gemfile because it requires sqlite3